# Cannot assign to function call when looping through and converting excel files

Tags: python

With this code:

```
    xls = pd.ExcelFile('test.xlsx')
    sn = xls.sheet_names
    for i,snlist in list(zip(range(1,13),sn)):
        'df{}'.format(str(i)) =  pd.read_excel('test.xlsx',sheet_name=snlist, skiprows=range(6))
```

I get this error:

> 'df{}'.format(str(i)) =  pd.read_excel('test.xlsx',sheet_name=snlist,
> skiprows=range(6))
> ^ SyntaxError: cannot assign to function call

I can't understand the error and how solve. What's the problem?
df+str(i) also return error

i want to make result as:
df1 = pd.read_excel.. list1...
df2 = pd.read_excel... list2....

Comment: The error message is pretty clear. `=` is assignment and you cannot assign something to a function call. Not sure what you don’t understand about this. What is `'df{}'.format(str(i)) = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx',sheet_name=snlist, skiprows=range(6))` supposed to do?

Comment: You're missing some basics on Python data types.  You're trying to assign to a temporary string -- the result of a function call.  This is a contradiction; it's a simple version of trying to change a constant, such as `"hello" = "a" + "b"`.

Comment: i want to make as  ..
df1 = pd.read_excel,..,.. list1..
df2 = pd.read_excel ... list 2....

df+str(i) also return error

Comment: @신동희 see the possible resolutions below -- either use a dict or a list

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't assign the result of `df.read_excel` to `'df{}'.format(str(i))` -- which is a *string* that looks like `"df0"`, `"df1"`, `"df2"` etc. That is why you get this error message. The error message is probably confusing since its treating this as assignment to a "function call".

It seems like you want a list or a dictionary of `DataFrame`s instead.

To do this, assign the result of `df.read_excel` to a *variable*, e.g. `df` and then `append` that to a list, or add it to a dictionary of `DataFrame`s.

As a list:

```
dataframes = []
xls = pd.ExcelFile('test.xlsx')
sn = xls.sheet_names
for i, snlist in list(zip(range(1, 13), sn)):
    df = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx', sheet_name=snlist, skiprows=range(6))
    dataframes.append(df)
```

As a dictionary:

```
dataframes = {}
xls = pd.ExcelFile('test.xlsx')
sn = xls.sheet_names
for i, snlist in list(zip(range(1, 13), sn)):
    df = pd.read_excel('test.xlsx', sheet_name=snlist, skiprows=range(6))
    dataframes[i] = df
```

In both cases, you can access the `DataFrame`s by indexing like this:

```
for i in range(len(dataframes)):
    print(dataframes[i])
# Note indexes will start at 0 here instead of 1
# You may want to change your `range` above to start at 0
```

Or more simply:

```
for df in dataframes:
    print(df)
```

In the case of the dictionary, you'd probably want:

```
for i, df in dataframes.items():
    print(i, df)
# Here, `i` is the key and `df` is the actual DataFrame
```

If you really do want `df1`, `df2` etc as the keys, then do this instead:

```
dataframes[f'df{i}'] = df
```